# moment generating function existence question

Tags: probability-theory

For a bounded random variable, it is easy to prove that all moments are finite. Does it follow that the moment generating function always exist?

Comment: If $X$ is bounded then so is $\exp (tX)$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the boundedness of $X$ implies the boundedness of $e^{tX}$ and therefore its integrability over the probability measure. (As Bertrand R. said)